# running two queries and then joining the results alasql promise notation

Tags: alasql

I currently can use the following promise notation as in wiki..

```
alasql.promise('SELECT * FROM XLS("mydata.xls") WHERE lastname LIKE "A%" and city = "London" GROUP BY name ')
      .then(function(res){
           console.log(res); // output depends on mydata.xls
      }).catch(function(err){
           console.log('Does the file exists? there was an error:', err);
      });
```

What I need to do is run two queries and then merge the result data using custom js..

I could initialise two arrays before running the query and inside then block copy the query result to the array but is this the right way to handle such a situation.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: The correct way is to get data into tables and join them in the select. If you give some input on what data you have and what you expect as output I can take a look at it.